# Append text in a python script file in bash

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am using the gawk command in a bash script to append some lines in a python script file called test.py. The problem is that sometimes the file is saved as a text file and it's blank. Is there something to add in the gawk in order to not save it as a text file?

```
gawk -i inplace 'NR==455{print "try:\n Mesh_1.ExportMED( r\047/'${path}'/'Template_${step_x}_${step_y}'/Mesh_1.med\047,\
0, SMESH.MED_V2_2, 1, None ,1)\n pass\nexcept:\n print \047ExportToMEDX() failed. \
Invalid file name?\047"}1' test.py
```

Comment: *Why* would you do this?

Comment: because the lines I want to append to the text file change as this test.py file is part of a while loop

Comment: Can't you do all in Python?

Comment: I think the question is, why are you trying to *automate* this change to the Python script, instead of just making the change (or using a tool like `patch` which is *designed* to update source code)?

Comment: The script I wrote is a bash script, the thing is that the lines are added but randomly some files are saved as text files and therefore blank